# Oracle APEX problem with default authentication schema

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am using custom authentication for one app, and now all apps which I create I need to switch to that custom schema to be able to login.

How to solve that?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have a workspace and - in the same workspace - there are 11 different applications. Some of them user my "custom" authentication scheme, while others use Apex Authentication. I never had to switch **all** applications to either of them (i.e. the custom scheme, as you're saying).

So:

- while in App. Builder
- choose any application
- navigate to Shared Components
- go to Authentication Schemes
- select authentication scheme (from the list)

  - I presume that would be "Application Express Authentication"; currently, it is "Custom scheme" (or whatever its name is)
- click **Make current scheme** to *switch* to chosen scheme

Comment: I tried now, and I can't login with APEX user, I am using the same user as in workspace.

Comment: I have a user in custom schema which has the same name and password as APEX user. When I tried with new APEX user it works.